# Join only if one line line intersects buffer. Do not if two

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, buffer, spatial-join

I've got a road network (line features) and a trip of GPS-Points. I want to join attributes from the road network to every point. So for each point i create a buffer. If the buffer intersects with a line feature, the attribtes are written to the point. That is all no problem. However I do not want to write attributes to points if the buffer intersects with to or more lines. Any ideas how to do this?
I work in ArcGIS. Is there a way to do this without using python?

Comment: This appears to be a cross post of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27065858/820534

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved in several steps.

1. Run a Spatial Join for your buffer polygons and road network layers (right-click the buffer polygons layer in the TOC and choose Join and Relates > Join).
   [image]

You will get an output polygon feature class which contains information on how many road features were located (even partially) within the buffered polygons.
[image]

2. Run a Join between the output feature class obtained in the step 1 and the source buffered polygons layer to find out which features you do not want to take into analysis (when you run Intersect and copying attributes).
3. Either set up a definition query or do a selection > export data to a new feature class when you have selected those features that have either null or 1 values (which are valid in your case) in the Count field.

If you use ModelBuilder to automate the workflow, please use the [Add Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Add_Join/001700000064000000/) GP tool and [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Spatial_Join/00080000000q000000/) GP tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That should work. Any idea how i could do this in modelbuilder. I can't find the join from "joins and relates" from the TOC in the toolbox.

Comment: @daverous, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Here's a good way to work this out in modelbuilder https://geonet.esri.com/thread/35325